# mkdir: cannot create directory No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I can't find a solution for this problem. I would like to create a script that creates a folder, using the current date as its name. The script should then copy all content from the current folder to newly created folder.
I tried following things already that doesn't work:

- use "mkdir -p" to create parent directories
- not using relative path with "pwd"

But when I try and create a directory out of an script in the terminal(also bash) I can create perfectly fine directories with the date inside. (following command)

> mkdir backup$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M)

### My Code

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M)
PWD=$(pwd)
FILENAME=backup$DATE

if [ -d "backup/" ]; then
    mkdir -p backup/$FILENAME
    cp -r * backup/$FILENAME
else
    mkdir -p backup/
    mkdir -p backup/$FILENAME
    cp -r * backup/$FILENAME
fi
```

### Error thrown

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘backup/backup18-01-2022_12:43’: No such file or directory

Comment: You apparently lack write access to the directory. Voting to close as unreproducible / simple pilot error.

Comment: With `mkdir -p`, you can create all the directories in one step, no need for `mkdir -p backup/`

Comment: thanks for your answer glenn, I just changed my code.

Comment: Tripleee, I have every rights possible(drwxrwxrwx) on the backup/ Folder, on the script, on the folder in which the script is located and on the data I want to copy/backup.

Comment: Is your script started periodicaly using ```cron```? (this is a common source of error)

Comment: maybe the terminal test and the script test are not done from the same location on the disk? what is the output of ```pwd``` when testing with a terminal? what is the output of ```pwd``` when the script is run?

Comment: **Always** quote variables in command line arguments: `mkdir -p backup/"$FILENAME"`

Comment: If you format your date year-month-day, the files are automatically sorted chronologically in the directory listing.

Comment: The command `mkdir -p 'backup/backup18-01-2022_12:43'` works fine. The problem must be anything else. Btw `PWD` gets never used.

Comment: Can you share ls -ld backup ? Possible that 'backup' is a symlink ?

Answer (score 1):

This really looks like the backup directory didn't exist, and wasn't getting created

```
!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                            

# for extra debugging / tracing, uncomment this:                                                                                                                                               
# set -x                                                                                                                                                                                       

DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M)
PWD=$(pwd)
FILENAME=backup$DATE

# printing out our variables, to make sure there's nothing weird in them:                                                                                                                      
printf "\nDATE:     %s\n" "${DATE}"
printf "PWD:      %s\n" "${PWD}"
printf "FILENAME: %s\n\n" "${FILENAME}"

# I took out the if statments ( they become redundant with mkdir -p )                                                                                                                          
# and also removed the cp action, since it's not really relevant here.                                                                                                                         


printf "Without the backup directory created, I'll spit out the error you had:\n\n"
mkdir    backup/${FILENAME}


printf "\n\nBut by using the -p argument, it can create the directory:\n\n"
mkdir -p backup/${FILENAME}

ls -l backup

printf "\n\n"
```

and looking at the output:

```
$ ./backup.sh 

DATE:     09-02-2024_15:49
PWD:      /home/matt/data/playground/stackoverflow
FILENAME: backup09-02-2024_15:49

Without the backup directory created, Ill spit out the error you had:

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘backup/backup09-02-2024_15:49’: No such file or directory


But by using the -p argument, it can create the directory:

total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 matt matt 4096 Feb  9 15:49 backup09-02-2024_15:49
```

the output message is identical to what was originally displaying.

I modified the code you had a bit that includes `set -x`  which is a tracing / debugging utility for bash... and I printed out your variables ( just in case something was weird with them ) ... and the if/else/fi statement was doing the same thing if the directory was there or not, because `mkdir -p backup` was in both, so they were effectively redundant.

By running the code multiple times the error doesn't exist, and you can see the output of the new backup directories with the timestamp in them.

There wasn't really more to go on, but being able to replicate the output gives me a fair bit of confidence that the directory just wasn't getting properly created ( perhaps from a previous iteration of code without `mkdir -p`)

hopefully this gives a bit of insight into how to debug things in the future.